# Unable to think about argument involving integratibility of a function in a research paper

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

I am self studying a research paper in analytic number theory and I am unable to think about how G(x,z) is integrable with z belonging to Complex Number and |z|$\geq$1.

Adding relevant image 
[image]

> My question is-> How continuity of second function given as 3 integrals results in integratibility of G(x,z) . In G(x,z) there is z in place of 1 in 2nd function in denominator also as number of terms are (n+1) in 1st function and 3 in 2nd function, so how would $ Li_2(t) $be in case of G(x,z). 
>   Here $Li_n(z)$= $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ $ \frac{z^k} {(k+1)^n}$ .

Can someone please explain. I shall be really thankful.

Comment: My French is a little rusty but for any $z\neq0$ the function $G$ (as a function of $x$) is bounded and hence integrable in the given interval.

Comment: @lcv  you are right!! I am sorry to ask it.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @lcv but not every bounded function is integrable on a interval then how did you deduced it's integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me call $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$. From the problem it seems that $k\ge3$. 
Define also

\begin{align}
 G(x,z) &= \frac{1}{(z-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k)^2} \\
F(x,t) &= \frac{1}{(1-x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k t)^2} \\
G(x,z) &= \frac{1}{z^2} F(x,1/z)
\end{align}

So the integrability of $G$ can be deduced from that of $F$. First of all, if $|z|>1$ $G(x,z)$ is bounded as a function of $x$. Since the integration region $[0,1]^k$ is compact, $G(x,z)$ is integrable on $[0,1]^k$ for $|z|>1$. Hence we only need to worry about $|z|=1$.

The point is that the integral can computed exactly. We will compute the integral of $F$.

First use, for $|x|<1$

$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^n
$$

With this you can show that

$$
\int_0^1 dx_1    \int_0^1 dx_2 \cdots\int_0^1 dx_k F(x,t) = \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{k-1} (t)}{t}
$$

(so there is a mistake in your book). This formula, derived for $|t|<1$, defines actually an analytic function (hence continuous and bounded) also for $|t|=1$.

Comment: did you accidentally wrote z>1 as z<1  in line 9 ?

Comment: Yes sorry, a typo. Corrected

Comment: what line is mistake, can you please tell. It's not textbook, it's a published research paper. Irrationality d'une infinite de valeurs de la fonction zera aux entiers impairs ( by T rivoal and Keith Ball) Page 6 ( 199 ) of paper.

Comment: also$ \frac{ Li_{ k-1}(t) } { t}$ = $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac { t^l} { (l+1)^{k-1}  × t} $  and F(x, t) = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( x_1 x_2   ... x_k t)^n $ . So, how are they equal.

Comment: Oh of course I forgot the integration sign.  Corrected now. The mistake is in the last equation of your picture (to be compared with my last equation for the particular case $k=3$).